# About proving that $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb {D}_n) \cong \mathbb {Z}_n \rtimes \operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb {Z}_n)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, dihedral-groups, semidirect-product

How can I prove that
$$
\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb {D}_n)  \cong \mathbb {Z}_n \rtimes \operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb {Z}_n),
$$
where $\mathbb {D}_n$ is the [dihedral group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group).

Can someone help me please? Thank you.

Comment: Do you know how many automorphisms a dihedral group has? That might be a good start. Remember that isomorphisms must send generating sets to generating sets (To think about automorphisms, not the overall statement).

Comment: @pjs36 I can propose that $n\phi(n)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Theorem $7.2$ [here](http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2013/REUPapers/Sommer-Simpson.pdf), where it is shown that the short exact sequence
$$
1\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_n\rightarrow \operatorname{Aut}(D_n)\rightarrow \operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_n)\rightarrow 1
$$
splits, which just says that the middle group is a semidirect product of the outer ones.

Comment: You are welcome !