# Smallest symmetric group which embeds $D_n \rtimes Aut(D_n)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, representation-theory, dihedral-groups, semidirect-product

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1599089/the-smallest-symmetric-group-s-m-into-which-a-given-dihedral-group-d-2n-em) answers which the smallest symmetric group to embeds $D_n$  of order $2 n$.

I would like to know what is the smallest symmetric group which embeds $D_n \rtimes Aut(D_n)$.

I understand that to know the answer I need to know the order of the elements in the product. [From here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Order_of_semidirect_product_is_product_of_orders), I can say that the order of a semidirect product is the product of the orders of the operand groups. We know that 
$$Aut(D_n) = C_n \rtimes_\phi Aut(C_n)$$. So, $$|D_n \rtimes Aut(D_n)| = |D_n \rtimes (C_n \rtimes_\phi Aut(C_n))|
$$.

Then I have shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2090063/order-of-d-n-rtimes-autd-n) that:

$$
|D_n \rtimes Aut(D_n)| = 2 n^3  \prod_{p|n} \left(1 - \frac{1}{p}\right)
$$

I am not sure how to proceed from here.

PS. I initially thought that $|Aut (D_n)|$ is also $2 n$ which is incorrect as  Dietrich pointed out. So, I fixed it.

Comment: Your last sentence is not true, since $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb {D}_n) \cong \mathbb {Z}_n \rtimes \operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb {Z}_n)$, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1557271/about-proving-that-operatornameaut-mathbb-d-n-cong-mathbb-z-n-rtime?rq=1).

Comment: @DietrichBurde, are you suggesting that the order of the automorphism group may not be the same as the order of the original group?

Comment: Yes, I do. Do you see this differently? Take for example $Q_8$ and its automorphism group $S_4$, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/195932/automorphism-group-of-the-quaternion-group).

Comment: @DietrichBurde, I just checked, there is no reason that automorphism preserves order.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, I have updated the question.